# OkHttp with Certificate Pinning

Tags: android, ssl, self-signed, okhttp

My Android project (OkHttp 3.3.1) currently works with my HTTPS web service (my PC, IIS web server, Asp.Net Web API, self-signed certificate)

**Helper methods:**

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory()
        throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.iis_cert);
    Certificate ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    caInput.close();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}

private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
    return new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {            
            HostnameVerifier hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
            return hv.verify("BNK-PC.LOCALHOST.COM", session);
        }
    };
}
```

**Code A:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())
        .hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
```

After reading [this CertificatePinner guide](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html), my project also works well when adding `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` as below:

**Code B:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())
        .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
        .hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
```

According to [this Wiki](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS), **certificate pinning increases security**.

However, actually I have not clearly understood this idea. So my question is that whether I need to or have to use `certificatePinner` or not when my app still works with the **Code A**. In other words, does **Code B** have better security than **Code A**?

Comment: There are many good articles, Check [here](http://blog.lumberlabs.com/2012/04/why-app-developers-should-care-about.html).

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar many thanks for your link, I am reading, perhaps I need to read it many times to understand, too much security knowledge to know when I am not good at English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate Pinning should help with certain classes of attacks

1. *Any* trusted certificate authority gets hacked and generates valid certificates for your domain which a MITM attack e.g. by an invasive government.
2. Your app is running on a device with additional trusted certificates e.g. installed by the Corporation that supplied the phone.

I think generally if you issued your certificates from two major CA e.g. verisign, you would pin to their signing certificates rather than your own.  This is because you are likely to generate new certificates for your server as a routine thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with the 2nd (`...additional trusted certificates e.g. installed by the Corporation that supplied the phone`) do you mean that it's also a risk even though my app is internal use only?

Comment: Just that if someone can install new certificates on your phone, e.g. your company administrator, then they can read all traffic on your phone that doesn't use something like certificate pinning.

http://www.8bitavenue.com/2015/05/debugging-ios-and-android-ssl-connections-using-charles-proxy/

Comment: I have tried my app with 2 wifi networks (one has Charles proxy, the other has not). With the wifi having Charles proxy, `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found` always thrown although `.certificatePinner(certificatePinner)` used or not

Comment: Ok, well let's assume you got things up and working such that the certificate was correctly installed and your traffic was going through Charles. With certificate pinning you should be able to reject that connection and avoid the security breach against your users.

Comment: Hi Yuri, one more question please. If the hostname pinned (`developer.android.com`) is different from the hostname of the request (`github.com`), although my app still works, however, is cert pinning not really useful in this case, am I right?

Comment: Your app shouldn't still work. The hostname verifier should reject this. If it doesn't it's a bug.

Comment: It still works, my code `CertificatePinner certPinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add("developer.android.com", "sha256/ipnPWRpHyvnlT3Z/tqzbkXT7af49mGy7DZEZfrExAic=")                    
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .certificatePinner(certPinner)
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS")
                    .build();
            client.newCall(request)...`

Comment: Debugging to `CertificatePinner.java`, inside `public void check(String hostname, List<Certificate> peerCertificates)
      throws SSLPeerUnverifiedException {
    List<Pin> pins = findMatchingPins(hostname);
    if (pins.isEmpty()) return;` the `findMatchingPins` in this case will return empty list, so `check` will ignore the rest

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.  I thought you meant the wrong certificate was returned by the server.

One OkHttpClient may talk to multiple http hosts, e.g. if you redirect through url shorteners or fetch remote images after downloading HTML. So it only applies when the pattern matches the host exactly or *.host.com etc.

So this is expected. However unless you control the host, you probably shouldn't be pinning their certificates. Github do return the "Public-Key-Pins" header but this sort of thing makes me nervous if it goes wrong, so I'm not going to offer more advice.